# Drupal: showing different page layouts based on form data

Tags: forms

I'm trying to build a multi step form. Before the second step I have to process the data inserted in step one and display different layout and form fields based on the results.

I use "drupal_get_form" callback in _menu hooks to display the form, but I think I have to use a different approach, because I can't find a way to specify a template and\or HTML code this way.

What can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try ctools multistep wizard to generate the multi step form in Drupal. To start with Ctools wizard form a great example is given at the following link http://internetdevels.com/blog/ctools-multistep-wizard-example